# Python class inheriting multiprocessing: mocking one of the class objects

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance, multiprocessing

I have written a class that inherits the *multiprocessing.Process()* class. In the initialization I set some parameters, one of them is another class that writes to some file on my hard drive. For the purpose of unit testing I would like to mock this class instance in order to avoid actually writing to some file. Here is some minimal example:

```
import mock
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

class MyProcess(mp.Process):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyProcess, self).__init__()

        # the original code would create some instance of a file manipulation
        # class here:
        self._some_class = np.zeros(100)

    def run(self):

        # the following line would actually write to some file in the original
        # code:
        self._some_class.sum()

        for ii in range(10):
            print(str(ii))
            time.sleep(.01)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    proc = MyProcess()
#     proc._some_class = mock.Mock()

    proc.start()
    proc.join()
```

The code above should run as is. However, if I try to mock the class *_some_class* in the class *MyProcess* (= uncommenting the line in the main function) I get errors. Interestingly, I get the exact same errors if I try to initialize *self._some_class* with a function (e.g. replace line 13 in the code above with *self._some_class = lambda x: x/2 *). So my guess is that there is some problem with copying the objects in *MyProcess* when a new process is spawned. That raises two questions:

- Could somebody shed some light why it is not possible to initialize a class object with a function?
- How could I mock one of the class objects of *MyProcess*?

I would really appreciate any help...

EDIT 1 (more information on the error messages):

If I uncomment the line in the main function I get a bunch of errors, where I think the following should be the relevant one:

pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : it's not the same object as mock.Mock

EDIT 2 (found some relevant information):

I found the following [issue](https://code.google.com/p/mock/issues/detail?id=139) on google code, which seems to be related to my problem. Indeed, changing the mock in the main function to the following makes the code executable:

```
proc._some_class = mock.MagicMock()
proc._some_class.__class__ = mock.MagicMock
```

However, what I would be interested in for testing is the following call: *proc._some_class.some_method.called*, which is always *False* despite the fact that the method has obviously been called. I guess that has something to do with the workaround that I mentioned above.

EDIT 3 (workaround based on the suggestion of jb.):

One can work around the issue by calling the *run* method directly. The following code contains the main function and shows how to test the function using mocks:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    proc = MyProcess()
    proc._some_class = mock.MagicMock()
    proc.run()

    print(proc._some_class.sum.called)
```

Comment: I get a full list of errors but I would guess that the relevant one should be: *pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'mock.Mock'>: it's not the same object as mock.Mock*

Comment: @Veedrac: done, I moved the info from my comment to the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this does not address your question directly, please consider following approach. Inheriting from Process object might be make implementation easier, but (as you noted) can be very hard when doing unit-testing.

It would be much easier if you pass `run` function as a parameter to `Process` instance in that way you can test `run` function separately from the multiprocessing enviorment. If you need to test `run` behaviour in another process just create a callable object, and mock proper things inside.

Something along the lines:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

If you want to stick to your design you'd shouldn't use MagicMock, python multiprocessing interface relies on [pickling](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html), and mock library and pickling don't go [well together](https://code.google.com/p/mock/issues/detail?id=139). Just write your own mocking class.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I decided not to change the design itself but rather just access the run function of my class directly without spawning a new process. I will add the workaround to my original post.